# Collect List into a Map<Object1 , Map<Object2, Object3>> in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to iterate a list of objects. Each of object contains some variables of objects. More specifically:

```
public class KCenterDocumentMapping {
    private DigitalFileCategory digitalFileCategory;
    private DocumentType documentType;
    private KCenterCategory kCenterCategory;
    private KCenterFolder kCenterFolder;
    private KCenterDocumentType kCenterDocumentType;

    //setters & getters
}
```

My list is:

```
List<KCenterDocumentMapping> allMappings = db4.retrieveMapping();
```

The desired Map Structure is:

```
Map<DigitalFileCategory, Map<DocumentType, KCenterDocumentMapping>> kCenterDocumentMappingMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In my current implementation I received "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

```
Map<DigitalFileCategory, Map<DocumentType,KCenterDocumentMapping>> grouping = kCenterDocumentMappingList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(KCenterDocumentMapping::getDigitalFileCategory,
                        Collectors.mapping(KCenterDocumentMapping::getDocumentType, this)));
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of mapping, use groupingBy again. No need for 'this'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Collectors.mapping(KCenterDocumentMapping::getDocumentType, this) // this?
```

I think you are looking for is :

```
Collectors.toMap(KCenterDocumentMapping::getDocumentType,
         Function.identity())
```

`Collectors.mapping` accepts a `Function` and a `Collector` as input; `this` does not look like a `Collector`

Comment: Compiled and got this:




Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key KCenterDocumentMapping: 39
        at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
        at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1253)
        at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
        at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$45(Collectors.java:909)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)

Comment: @pkont well you do have a duplicate `Key` obviously. you need to merge them somehow logically. what happens when you have same key twice? do you want to collect your values into a `List` may be? So it would become `Map<DocumentType, List<KCenterDocumentMapping>>`

Comment: As I can see from the retrieved list I do not have duplication. 
The composite key of the "list" is the combination of DigitalFileCategory and DocumentType

Comment: @pkont well you **obviously** have a duplicate Key, otherwise you would not get the exception

Comment: Use the merge argument of `Collectors.toMap`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: @AKSW or `groupingBy(KCenterDocumentMapping::getDocumentType, Collectors.toList)`